# Moving from Webforms to MVC 4 some basics

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, webforms

Being used to Webforms I'm having an issue 'visualising' MVC

If I create a class (called Customers.vb) and add a string property

```
Public Property Customers_CustomerName() As String
```

... add this function to the controller

```
 Function Index() As ActionResult
        Dim vCustomers As New Customers

        vService = New Service1Client
        strSQL = "SELECT Cust_Name FROM Customers WHERE Customer_ID = 1"
        Dim vName As String = vService.ReturnScalarString(strSQL, 2)

        vCustomers.Customers_CustomerName = vName
        vService.Close()
        vService = Nothing

        ViewData("Customers") = vCustomers
        Return View("Customers_View")
    End Function
```

...and add this to the view

```
 Code
        Dim vCustomers As MVPTest.Customers = CType(ViewData("Customers"), MVPTest.Customers)
        Dim CustName As String = vCustomers.Customers_CustomerName
        Using (Html.BeginForm(Nothing, "Customers_/Edit/5", FormMethod.Post))
        @<p>
            @Html.TextBox("TB3", CustName)
            <input type="submit" value="test" />
        </p>

        End Using

    End Code
```

I now get the value in the textbox - but this seems a really long way round compared to WebForms where code-behind would simply be "TB2.value = vName" (where the text box is a generic input control with Runat="Server" - so I must be missing something.

Also I cannot find a way to post back a value in the textbox back to the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<HttpPost()>
    Function Edit(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal collection As FormCollection) As ActionResult
        Try
            Dim EditName As String = Convert.ToString(collection("TB3").ToString)


            Return RedirectToAction("Index")
        Catch
            Return View()
        End Try
    End Function
```